# Custom ReleaseTree is not showing the logs using Timber

Tags: android, release-builds, timber-android

I am using custom `ReleaseTree` for my application using Timber to filter the logs. But when building the release apk application logs are not showing in logcat. When using `Timber.DebugTree()` in release build logs are showing properly.

Here is my ReleaseTree class:

```
class ReleaseTree : Timber.Tree() {

    override fun log(priority: Int, tag: String?, message: String, throwable: Throwable?) {
        // Don't log VERBOSE, DEBUG and INFO
        if (priority == Log.VERBOSE) {
            return
        }


        if (priority == Log.ERROR){
            val t = throwable ?: Exception(message)

            // Crashlytics
            Crashlytics.setInt(CRASHLYTICS_KEY_PRIORITY, priority)
            Crashlytics.setString(CRASHLYTICS_KEY_TAG, tag)
            Crashlytics.setString(CRASHLYTICS_KEY_MESSAGE, message)
            Crashlytics.logException(t)
        }

    }

    companion object {
        private val CRASHLYTICS_KEY_PRIORITY = "Priority"
        private val CRASHLYTICS_KEY_TAG = "Tag"
        private val CRASHLYTICS_KEY_MESSAGE = "Message"
    }
}
```

How I am initializing the ReleaseTree from Application class:

```
Fabric.with(this, new Crashlytics());
Timber.plant(new ReleaseTree());
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a line missing in your method log.

You need to log into logcat from your custom tree

```
override fun log(priority: Int, tag: String?, message: String, throwable: Throwable?) {
        // Don't log VERBOSE, DEBUG and INFO
        if (priority == Log.VERBOSE) {
            return
        } else {
          Log.println(priority, tag, message);
        }


        if (priority == Log.ERROR){
            val t = throwable ?: Exception(message)

            // Crashlytics
            Crashlytics.setInt(CRASHLYTICS_KEY_PRIORITY, priority)
            Crashlytics.setString(CRASHLYTICS_KEY_TAG, tag)
            Crashlytics.setString(CRASHLYTICS_KEY_MESSAGE, message)
            Crashlytics.logException(t)
        }

    }
```

Comment: Worked for me but tag is null for release apk.